# Parent Process not Waiting for Children - C

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, wait

I am writing a program that is intended to pin the CPU usage, I am using it as a tool to measure performance. The program is fairly simple in that it spawns 5 child processes from the parent. Below is a snipped of my code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pid_t pid = 0; 
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    //create 5 additional processes
    if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        //do CPU intensive task
      break;
    }

  //fork error 
  if(pid == -1) {
    perror("<fork failed>\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  //if parent
  if(pid != 0)
    //wait for children to finish
    wait(NULL);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However the parent process exits right away, despite the wait(NULL) function. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how it could be fixed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the children are still running? You have not stated that explicitly.

Comment: Is wait failing?  And perhaps setting errno to EFAULT?

Comment: I am certain the children are still running, I can see them using 'top'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating five children but `wait` returns as soon as any one of them exits.  You want to wait for all of them, so you need to call `wait` repeatedly.  The `wait` function returns -1 and sets `errno` to `ECHILD` when you have no children left:

```
while (wait(NULL) != -1 || errno != ECHILD) {
    // nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **waitpid()** function call. in your case your spawning 5 child process. And overwriting the pid with latest child.

**wait()** waits for any of the child process to complete not all.

parent exits when any of the child completes its execution and sends a signal **SIGCHLD** back to calling process which is enough for it terminate.

so if you want all 5 child process to execute then parent to finish specify the pid's separately